# Using Iqueryable to return a list from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use IQueryable to return items from database. I'm not sure how to implement this. I've tried to return db.Phones.Where( from x in someQueryable); My error is Error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Iquerable

```
private IList<Phone> GetPhones(int carrierId, string emailaddress)
{
    string pattern = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,50})(@gmail|@GMail)(\.)(com|COM)$"; //regular expression
    Match match = Regex.Match(emailaddress, pattern);//matches users email domain address with regular expression

    IQueryable someQueryable = null; //need help
    if (match.Success) // if true it will do the following
    {
        someQueryable = from g in db.Phones //linq to sql
            where g.GovAllowed == true
            select g;
    }
    else
    {
        someQueryable = from c in db.Phones // linq to sql
            where c.CommerceAllowed == true
            select c;
    }

    return db.Phones.Where( from x in someQueryable);//need help on this to return the data from database whether true or false           
}
```

Comment: `someQueryable` must be `IQueryable<Phone>`. If you get errors please always tell which they are, "I'm getting syntax errors" doesn't mean much.

Comment: Also, what is the last statement supposed to do?

Comment: Do I change all the someQueryable to Iqueryable<Phone>?
Error: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Iquerable<Phone>. Select not found

Comment: I'm using a database where if is GovAllowed it will display certain phone types(iphones, galaxy, etc). If its CommerceAllowed it displays different phone types. I just need to return the list of phones every time once it match the string pattern.

Comment: The last statement doesn't make sense, that's why I asked. It's syntactically wrong and you don't need it. Just return `someQueryable`.ToList()`. Yes, change it to `IQueryable<Phone>`, that's what the words "must be" imply.

Comment: I changed ALL someQueryable to Iqueryable<Phone> and got more errors. I don't think I'm change the right one.

Comment: For the last statement I tried "return someQueryable.ToList();" but ToList(); does not list in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, someone has given it to you on a plate now. That's about what I was saying and hoped you would understand and somewhat discover yourself. Please, next time when you ask something, give more information (errors etc.), but first try to explain to yourself what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are getting syntax errors here? -->

```
return db.Phones.Where( from x in someQueryable);
```

try this..

```
IQueryable<Phone> someQueryable = null;

    if (match.Success)
    {
        someQueryable = from g in db.Phones
            where g.GovAllowed == true
            select g;
    }
    else
    {
        someQueryable = from c in db.Phones
            where c.CommerceAllowed == true
            select c;
    }

   return someQueryable.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, I was changing it in the wrong place. Thank you so much for the help!!!! :)